# How to share an image to Instagram Stories from Expo / React Native

Tags: react-native, expo

How do I share an image directly to an Instagram story using Expo / React Native?

This issue has already [been solved](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44600809/7869175) for iOS for normal Instagram posts, but not stories.

Facebook's [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram/sharing-to-stories/) explain how to do this for iOS and Android, but not React Native.

### Expected behavior:

Open Instagram story with the selected image.

### Current behavior:

Opens Instagram story with blank screen.

### The problem I'm facing:

I'm not quite sure how to generate a URI that fits Instagram's schema, as referenced in their [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram/sharing-to-stories/).

### Reproducible Snack

https://snack.expo.io/@nandorojo/share-to-instagram-story

Thank you so much!

Here is my code from the snack above:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, Linking, Image } from 'react-native';
import * as FileSystem from 'expo-file-system';

const url = 'https://source.unsplash.com/daily';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  _shareToStory = async () => {
    // download to device
    const { uri } = await FileSystem.downloadAsync(
      url,
      `${FileSystem.documentDirectory}meme.jpg`
    ).catch(e => console.log('instagram share failed', JSON.stringify(e), url));

    try {
      const encodedUrl = encodeURIComponent(uri);
      const instagramUrl = `instagram-stories://share?backgroundImage=${encodedUrl}`;
      Linking.openURL(instagramUrl);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Image source={{ uri: url }} style={{ height: 100, width: 100 }} />
        <Text style={styles.paragraph} onPress={this._shareToStory}>
          Share to Instagram Story
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
  paragraph: {
    margin: 24,
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Expo Managed Workflow, your options are very limited. As of SDK v38, afaik it's only possible to accomplish this on **Android**, and only if you're sharing a **background image** (due to missing Expo APIs for content permissions and pasteboard), then something like this might work:

```js
import * as FileSystem from 'expo-file-system'
import * as IntentLaucher from 'expo-intent-launcher'

// url of the file to share
const url = '....'

// some random temporary filename
const localFile = `${FileSystem.cacheDirectory}${uuid()}.jpg`

try {
  FileSystem.downloadAsync(url, localFile)
    .then(({ uri }) => {
      FileSystem.getContentUriAsync(uri).then(contentUri => {
        IntentLauncher.startActivityAsync(
          'com.instagram.share.ADD_TO_STORY',
          {
            data: contentUri,
            flags: 1, // FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION
            type: 'image/jpeg', // or other based on your file type
          }
        ).catch(console.warn)
      })
    })
    .catch(console.warn)
} finally {
  FileSystem.deleteAsync(localFile).catch(console.warn)
}
```

However, if you're using React Native (or have ejected to Expo Bare Workflow), then you have more options. I'd recommend using the RN community supported [react-native-share](https://react-native-community.github.io/react-native-share/docs/share-single#static-values-for-instagram-stories) library that works on both Android and iOS and supports all of the sharing options (plus many other services):

```js
import Share from 'react-native-share'

Share.shareSingle({
  method: Share.InstagramStories.SHARE_BACKGROUND_IMAGE,
  backgroundImage: '....' // url of the file to share
  social: Share.Social.INSTAGRAM_STORIES,
})
```