# Share is not working on iOS 13. Expo module

Tags: react-native, expo, ios13

SDK Version: 35
Platforms(Android/iOS/web/all): iOS : 13
After I updated my iPhone to iOS 13. Sharing doesn’t work when I choose Sharing to Instagram.
Nothing happens when I choose it.
Sharing is working with other social networks

iOS 13. SDK 35. Expo v35

```
handleShare = async () =>{
        this.setState({share : true, opa : 0.4})
        if(!this.state.downloaded){
            await this.handleDownload();
        }
        if(Platform.OS == 'ios'){
            try {
                const result = await Share.share({
                    message : this.state.uri,
                    url : this.state.uri,

                }, {
                    excludedActivityTypes : [
                        "net.whatsapp.WhatsApp.ShareExtension",
                    ]
                });
                if (result.action === Share.sharedAction) {
                    if (result.activityType) {
                    // shared with activity type of result.activityType
                    } else {
                    // shared
                    }
                } else if (result.action === Share.dismissedAction) {
                    this.setState({share: false, opa : 1})
                }
            } catch (error) {
                alert(error.message);
            }
        }
        else{
            Sharing.shareAsync(this.state.uri).then(() =>{
                this.setState({share : false, opa : 1})
            })
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like that's an issue, yes. There is a [feature request](https://expo.canny.io/feature-requests/p/make-it-possible-to-share-an-image-to-instagram-on-ios-and-android).

It looks like currently, you can share to Instagram on iOS if it's on the camera roll. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44600809/1333836) as an example.