# Share to Instagram feed using React Native EXPO

Tags: react-native, expo

Anyone has an idea on how to share photo on Instagram feed using React Native Expo ? I am using currently React Native linking or the openUrl, but it returns an error:
[See error here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QK61A.png)

Comment: Instead of using linking try using share https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/react-native/share/

Comment: Does this allow you to share photos on Instagram feed? @GuruparanGiritharan

Comment: This will open the popup for sharing

Comment: Yes it does, but it does but it doesnt have an option of sharing to instagram :)

Comment: Does the device/emulator you are using has Instagram installed? It seems like the device can't open the Insta app.

Comment: or maybe check this option https://stackoverflow.com/a/44600809/1435722